# Creating and using skins of dotnetnuke 7

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-7, dotnetnuke

I want to create the skin of dnn site and also want to make the "Install package" of the skin, and how to use it on my local site.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any good tutorials on this process for DNN 7. What I would recommend is that you download an existing Skin and start working with that.

If you are wanting to create a "package" with your changes, so that you can distribute that Skin elsewhere after making changes, I would start with a Skin that comes with the source code, as that may make things easier.

I just released a new open source skin yesterday that has a visual studio project (VS2013), and when you compile it in release mode, it creates the INSTALL and SOURCE packages. Though this skin requires Bootstrap 3 (comes in the skin) you can download from https://github.com/ChrisHammond/HammerFlex/releases grab the SOURCE package, upload that to your Host>Extensions page.

I have an older skin at http://multifunction.codeplex.com/ that uses VS2012